# Connection in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer. Below are the inputs:

1. Connection Name:Dbms
2. Username:[My Name]
3. Password:[Ubuntu Password]
4. ConnectionType:Basic
5. Role: default
6. Hostname: localhost
7. Port: 1521
8. SID: xe

Upon clicking Test an error is being displayed:

> Network Adapter could not establish connection

Comment: None of the 100+ existing questions I found with a search for *oracle network adapter could not establish connection* helped you?

Comment: How should I create a new connection?

Comment: How is that a response to what I asked you?

Comment: This was the message displayed when I clicked on test and it didn't say oracle network adapter.

Comment: *Oracle* is the database (used by **Oracle SQL Developer**), and the error message says **Network Adapter could not establish connection**.. Did you actually read the words in the message? Wait... Did you install Oracle (the database) at all? You need the database before you can use SQL Developer to work with it.

Comment: You need  a database https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303

Comment: 2. and 3. say that you entered "your name" and "Ubuntu password" - those should be "database username" and "password for that database user", not operating system ones.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, Sir I downloaded Oracle XE but I am not able to get "this container" as it is leading to Error 404 page not found.

Comment: @Utkarsh if you installed and ran xe, it should be running on your machine. can you connect with sqlplus on the command line? When you say '404' are you trying to load em express in your browser?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Sir I am able to connect with sqlplus on the command line.

Comment: then you should be good for SQL Developer too - but username and password would be what you used to connect in sqlplus - not your ubuntu credentials

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thank You, Sir, for the help. It worked.

Comment: @Utkarsh welcome to the wide, wonderful world for Oracle!